# ¿Cómo puedo formar matrices en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

En mi código pido mediante el ingreso de datos por teclado (`raw_input`) un `numero_x` de elementos, luego pudo los valores de `p`, `q`, `r`, `x` y `b` para cada elemento `X`. Lo que busco es formar una matroz con `X` filas y siete columnas (`p`, `q`, `r`, `x`, `b`, `z` y `y`). Tenía pensado inicialmente crear una matriz de ceros e ir llenando fila por fila, pero la verdad he tenido problemas al realizar el llenado.

Este es mi código:

```
from numpy.linalg import*;
numero_x_=raw_input("Teclea el numero:");
numero_x=int(numero_x_);
lista=zeros((numero_x,7));
print lista;
print lista.shape;
if numero_x>0:;
    for i in range(numero_x):;
        p_=raw_input("p: ");
        p=int(p_)
        q_=raw_input("q: ");
        q=int(q_);
        r_=raw_input("r: ");
        r=float(r_);
        x_=raw_input("x: ");
        x=float(x_);
        b_=raw_input("b:");
        b=float(b_);
        z=complex(r,x);
        y=1/z;
        y_info=array(([[p,q,r,x,b,z,y]]));
        print type(y_info);
        print y_info.shape;
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a StackOverflow, serías tan amable de quitar todas las mayúsculas y escribir de manera normal, ya que en Internet el escribir en mayúsculas es asociado con gritar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres tener una matriz de X x 7 elementos.

Si a priori sabes el número de filas que vas a tener lo más sencillo sería inicializar el array de ceros así:

`mi_arr = np.zeros((X, 7))`

Si no sabes el número de filas que vas a tener es más sencillo usar una lista de listas y después convertirlo a un `np.ndarray`. En este caso parece que sí está claro.

Por otra parte, tienes varias columnas que son `int`, varias que son `float` y varias que son `complex` por lo que tienes que usar un tipo de contenedor que no sea homogéneo y en numpy el único que hay es un `numpy.recarray` ([structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)), que es algo parecido a un `DataFrame` en pandas (salvando las distancias). Por tanto, para crear tu array heterogéneo puedes hacer...

Modificando un poco tu código y comentando algunas cosas:

```
# Nunca hagas este tipo de imports puesto que pierdes la traza
# de donde viene cada cosa y puedes contaminar el espacio
# de nombres obteniendo efectos indeseados
# from numpy.linalg import*;
import numpy as np
x = int(input("Teclea el número de filas:"))
mi_arr = np.array(
    np.zeros((x)), 
    dtype = [
        ('p', int),
        ('q', int),
        ('r', float),
        ('x', float),
        ('b', float),
        ('z', complex),
        ('y', complex)
    ]
) 
for i in range(x):
    p_ = input("p: ")
    mi_arr['p'][i] = int(p_)
    q_ = input("q: ")
    mi_arr['q'][i] = int(q_)
    r_ = input("r: ")
    mi_arr['r'][i] = float(r_)
    x_ = input("x: ")
    mi_arr['x'][i] = float(x_)
    b_ = input("b:")
    mi_arr['b'][i] = float(b_)
    mi_arr['z'][i] = complex(mi_arr['r'][i], mi_arr['x'][i])
    mi_arr['y'][i] = 1. / mi_arr['z'][i]
print(mi_arr)
```

Reitero, si lo he entendido bien, lo anterior haría lo que necesitas. Algunas cosas a comentar de tu código.

- En Python no hay que terminar las líneas con `;`. Ese símbolo se usa solo para varias declaraciones en la misma línea, por ejemplo, `x = 1; y = 2`.
- Ten cuidado con el operador división en python 2.x ya que puede tener efectos indeseados. En mi código (penúltima línea) he puesto `1. / ...` en lugar de `1 / ...`.
- El código que he puesto es compatible con Python 2.x y Python 3.x pero `input`, `range`, `/`,..., no funcionan exactamente igual.
- Estamos en 2016, deberías considerar seriamente la opción de usar python 3.x

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias,  lo de los puntos y comas nada más lo puse aquí para referenciar los cambios de línea. Déjame checar el código que me proporcionaste para probarlo. Agradezco tu amable atención.

Answer (score -1):

Saludos de antemano, agradezco tu amable atención, ya lo probé y funciona correctamente (había tenido un error al escribir el código así que te pido una disculpa).Aprovechando de tu amabilidad tengo otras preguntas que me gustaría me pudieras apoyar, en un vector estructurado (structured array) cómo puedo realizar una búsqueda de un valor máximo en una columna ya que en una matriz convencional solo utilizo el comando max y especifico el numero de columna en donde comenzar la búsqueda(max(:,número de columna)).La siguiente pregunta si en la matriz generada deseo realizar una búsqueda en la columna "p" y en la columna "q", por ejemplo buscar las veces que se repita p=1 en la columna "p" y las veces que se repita q=1 en la columna "q", para que una vez identificados esos elementos, realizar una sumatoria de los respectivos elementos de la columna "z". Finalmente, hay alguna forma de convertir el vector estructurado a un vector convencional ? o tú recomiendas seguirlo manejando como vector estructurado?. Agradezco tu amable atención.

Comment: No uses el mismo hilo para formular más preguntas. Cada pregunta debe tener su propio hilo para que la gente las pueda encontrar y todos ahorremos tiempo y recursos. Así que, por favor, elimina tu comentario de más arriba (http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13662/2816) y abre una nueva pregunta en un hilo nuevo y te intentamos responder por ahí.